# Magento Attributes

Tags: attributes

I'm having difficulty creating attributes (flavors) for my products.

I would like to make this flavor attribute appear just below or above the "add cart" button.

Could someone explain me how to do this?

For all the attributes that I have created, none have been able to make appear in this position.

See this site: http://magento2.demo.ubertheme.com/neve-studio-dance-jacket.html

Instead of colors, put flavors. See image!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check your settings for your EAV's, is the Flavour set to view on the frontend? You can check this in

> Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes

The setting should be identical to below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Size / Color are indicative of a configurable product family.

**Set up your attribute**
Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes:
Create a global attribute "flavor"
Set "Use To Create Configurable Product" to "Yes"
Set "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end" to "Yes"
Add as many options as you'll need.
 - If the options all have the same sort order, then it defaults to alphabetical.

**Create your configurable product** (Food Syrup)
Catalog > Manage Products > Add Product
Set "Product Type" to "Configurable"
Select "Flavor" as your configurable by.
Select "Size" as your configurable by.

**Create your simple product(s)** 
For something like a 32 oz. Vanilla food syrup
Select "Flavor" as "Vanilla"
Select "Size" as "32 oz."

For something like a 32 oz. Chocolate food syrup
Select "Flavor" as "Chocolate"
Select "Size" as "32 oz."

Make sure the Simple products are Associated with the configurable, this will give you the configurable options for that product.